# Eager loading for one to one relationship in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, eager-loading

Does anyone know if is there the problem with one to one relation in EF Core and Eager Loading or the problem is my poorly knowledge instead?

For example, if I have one simple one to one relation like this:

```
    public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Biography Biography { get; set; }
    }



    public class Biography
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string BiographyResume { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
    }

    public class OneDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }


        public OneDbContext(DbContextOptions<OneDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }
    }
```

Here is the Migration:

```
    public partial class CreateAuthorsTable : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Authors",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Authors", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Biography",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    BiographyResume = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    DateOfBirth = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    PlaceOfBirth = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Nationality = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    AuthorId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Biography", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Biography_Authors_AuthorId",
                        column: x => x.AuthorId,
                        principalTable: "Authors",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Biography_AuthorId",
                table: "Biography",
                column: "AuthorId",
                unique: true);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Biography");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Authors");
        }
    }
```

And now, in Controller everything is fine without Eager Loading:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AuthorsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly OneDbContext context;

        public AuthorsController(OneDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Author>> GetAuthors()
        {
            return await context.Authors.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

But when I use Eager Loading it doesn't return anything.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Author>> GetAuthors()
        {
            return await context.Authors.Include(a => a.Biography).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Tested with Postman:

```
https://localhost:44355/api/authors
```

for: return await context.Authors.ToListAsync();
It returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Luka",
        "lastName": "Jovic",
        "biography": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Stefan",
        "lastName": "Savic",
        "biography": null
    }
]
```

for: return await context.Authors.Include(a => a.Biography).ToListAsync();
It returns:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://localhost:44355/api/authors.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

Comment: EF Core wise everything looks ok. Are you sure the query doesn't return anything or your endpoint doesn't return data because of circular reference and serialization? i.e. is `list` empty here `var list = await context.Authors.Include(a => a.Biography).ToListAsync(); return list;`?

Comment: No, It's not empty. It returns Author and related Biography objects when I debugged.

Comment: This proves that the problem is not EF Core related. EF Core has no problems with circular references, but (some) serializers like JSON do. See [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization).

Comment: Yes man. It was serialization related problem. Thanks a lot. I didn't think in that direction at all.